# Why using Tyristor (SCR) for inverting the DC voltage in HVDC systems?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, power-electronics

In High Voltage 3 PHASE  Transmission Systems the voltage needs to be rectified (from the AC generation source to DC), transmitted, and then inverted back (From DC to AC). For doing this, usually LCC (Line commutated converter) are used. LCC consists generally of SCR thyristor valves, and as we know, thyristor can be controlled with a firing angle  when the voltage between anode and cathode is positive. So it can be controlled only for the turning ON, while for turning off a reverse voltage neeed to be applied.

Now, everything is clear for the rectifing part (Thyristors rectify the voltage as a common diode when the AC half-wave is positive and then is turned OFF automatically).

But what happens for the inverting part, if we cannot control the turning off? I mean, how can we create a sine wave at the AC output if we have a DC voltage that is constantly applied to the thyristor (we have always the condition for turning on but not for turning off, since V_DC is always positive) ?[image]